# error installing Tensorflow via docker

Tags: linux, docker, machine-learning, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried to run this

```
docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0 bash
```

but I got this error. Why I get this error(it says: Unable to find image 'tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0' locally) and starts downloading and then it stops dowloading and says timeout? could you pls help me?

Unable to find image 'tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0' locally

1.1.0: Pulling from tensorflow/tensorflow

c62795f78da9: Pull complete

d4fceeeb758e: Pull complete

5c9125a401ae: Pull complete 
0062f774e994: Downloading

6b33fd031fac: Downloading

353b34ef0a98: Downloading

4f6aefc14b68: Downloading

ce066374c6ca: Downloading 7.505 MB/115.7 MB

c0755a91ab3a: Downloading  5.92 MB/17.13 MB

f03279b52d25: Download complete

d1c27c29b7e3: Download complete

23807c5f4b3e: Downloading

docker: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 
127.0.0.1:58167->127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout.
See 'docker run --help'.

nastaran@nastaran-VirtualBox:~$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is your internet speed issue, try running small sample docker containers like hello world.